# Removing leading space of string in C and copy to the dest array

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to copy a trimmed string with leading whitespaces removed and store into dest array using pointer / without a pointer.

This is what I tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h> 
void trim_copy(char dest[], char src[]){
  char *p = src;
  size_t i;
  size_t counter = 0;
  size_t length = strlen(src);
  while(!isspace(src[counter]) && counter < length){
    p++;
    counter++; /*move the pointer to next index of string if it's a space*/
  }
  for (i = 0; i< length-counter; i++) {
    dest[i] = *p; 
    p++;
  }

}

int main(void){
  char string_with_space_dest[20];
  ltrim_copy(string_with_space_dest, "       hello");
  printf("after removing leading space %s\n",string_with_space_dest );
  return 0;
}
```

Prints out:

```
after removing leading space        hello
```

It compiles, but not working at all.

what if the src array was const and you can't use a pointer?

```
void trim_copy(char dest[], const char src[]){}
```

Comment: Code at least needs a `dest[i] = = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

isspace function is used to check if the argument contains any whitespace characters, so you need to remove the not operator because you want to skip the spaces and at the end after copying into dest array you need to assign the null character to dest array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h> 
void ltrim_copy(char dest[], char src[]){
  char *p = src;
  size_t i;
  size_t counter = 0;
  size_t length = strlen(src);
  while(isspace(src[counter]) && counter < length){
    p++;
    counter++; /*move the pointer to next index of string if it's a space*/
  }
  for (i = 0; i< length-counter; i++) {
    dest[i] = *p; 
    p++;
  }
  dest[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void){
  char string_with_space_dest[20];
  ltrim_copy(string_with_space_dest, "       hello");
  printf("after removing leading space %s\n",string_with_space_dest );
  return 0;
}
```